# How to import package in bash without ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, bash, importerror

I had an error 'ModuleNotFoundError' when I run python file in .sh file.

First this is directory structure.

```
- my_project/
--- common_lib/
----- __init__.py
----- my_module.py
--- dir_1/
----- test.py
----- test.sh
```

And this is contents of each file.

> common_lib/**init**.py

```
def test_func():
    print(1)
```

> common_lib/my_module.py

```
def module_func():
    print("This is module.")
```

> dir_1/test.py

```
import common_lib as cl

cl.test_func()
```

> dir_1/test.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

python test.py
```

When I run **test.py** file directly using editor such as 'vs code' or 'pycharm', I got the right result '1'.
But when I run test.sh file, I got the following error.

> **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common_lib'**

How can I import python package without 'No module Error' in this case?

Comment: Where do you execute the shell script? If not in `my_project` you have to add the directory to PYTHONPATH environment variable. Note, that definition of functions in an `__init__.py` is unexpected; that file should do any required initializations or stay empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place an (empty) `__init__.py` into your package root as well as all subdirectories. Then you can call the script as a module out of `dir_1`:

```
.
├── __init__.py
├── common_lib
│   └── __init__.py
└── dir_1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test.py
    └── test.sh
```

test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd .. && python -m dir_1.test
```

Output:

```
./test.sh
1
```

Have a look at the [Packages-docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more details.